# Some more polite ways to tell a stalker, or someone you don't like, to go away

Tags: politeness

We had a party at my former school canteen yesterday night.
While I was enjoying the food, I could feel that someone had been staring at me.
 Later, when he tried to get close to me, I said "Go away".
I don't know him, but thinking that he might be a student of my former school, so I just politely kept telling him to go away but the words that I used most was "go away"
Instead of "Go away", what can I say?

Comment: Being polite to a stalker may only encourage them.

Comment: Excuse me, but No! I'm not interested.

Comment: We need to know more about why you don't like him. It is a party after all, so of course people will try to hook up with other people. When you say "stalker", this means obsessively following you around. Is this the case? At that point polite won't work. Basically, I am saying you can't use "polite" and "stalker" in the same sentence.

Comment: First time: "Go away." Second time: "Go away." Third time: "Which part of 'go away' did you not understand?" Fourth time: "I've asked you to leave me alone three times now; if you don't leave me alone, I'm going to report you for harassment."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Please excuse me, I would like to be left alone."

It's polite, firm, and if he responds "why?" you could say:

> "I don't feel comfortable around you. Please leave."

Answer (score 1):

The polite thing would be to make an excuse to not be in the persons company and if it got really out of hand to ask them to leave because they are bothering you. If "Go away" is your starting point then you can pretty much say anything that isn't outright nasty and its a step in the right direction.

With a stalker though, you want to go the opposite direction. If the person is a proper weirdo then there is a good chance that most people are not that kind to them and so your perceived kindness weighs more than the meaning behind your words. If you are less bad than the average then you become comparatively good.

However:

Looking at someone is not stalking, unless you are going out of your way to watch them in secret. Neither is not obeying someone when told to "go away", that is just standing up for yourself. If you were to go away and he were to follow you after repeatedly requesting that he not, then that would be stalking.

The situation you described is not a Stalker situation. Did he follow you to this party or home from it? If not then there is just as much chance he was there for his own reasons and only happened meet you there. Unless the stalking started after this point then you are just making drama out of nothing. From the description it appears as though you met someone and you didn't like them so you are calling them nasty things.

It would seem plausible that this person just wanted to talk to you and then got embarrassed and didn't know how to leave without being humiliated. "Go away" is an extremely impolite thing to say to someone and if anyone else witnessed this then he would have been in a very difficult social situation.